# Understanding the stack trace

Tags: ios, xcode, stack-trace

I'm trying to better understand what the stack trace means. I have a two specific questions in this case.

1 - Does this stack trace mean that the method setOutcome: is unrecognized by an instance of a Task object?

2 - Can a method be unrecognized if the parameter passed in does not match the class of the expected parameter?

```
012-03-30 01:53:57.988 Arbonne[17625:15203] -[Task setOutcome:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x81b6b60 
2012-03-30 01:53:58.151 Arbonne[17625:15203] ERROR main [Line 20] Uncaught exception: -[Task setOutcome:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x81b6b60 
2012-03-30 01:53:58.154 Arbonne[17625:15203] ERROR main [Line 21] Stack trace: ( 
0 CoreFoundation 0x01d8903e __exceptionPreprocess + 206 
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x01f1acd6 objc_exception_throw + 44 
2 CoreFoundation 0x01d8acbd -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 253 
3 CoreFoundation 0x01cefed0 ___forwarding___ + 432 
4 CoreFoundation 0x01cefcb2 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50 
5 Arbonne 0x00030d5d -[TaskViewController addTask:] + 237 
6 CoreFoundation 0x01d8ae99 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 73 
7 UIKit 0x0081a14e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96 
8 UIKit 0x00a58a0e -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 145 
9 CoreFoundation 0x01d8ae99 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 73 
10 UIKit 0x0081a14e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96 
11 UIKit 0x0081a0e6 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61 
12 UIKit 0x008c0ade -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66 
13 UIKit 0x008c0fa7 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 503 
14 UIKit 0x008c0266 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 549 
15 UIKit 0x0083f3c0 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 513 
16 UIKit 0x0083f5e6 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 273 
17 UIKit 0x00825dc4 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 464 
18 UIKit 0x00819634 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 8196 
19 GraphicsServices 0x02653ef5 PurpleEventCallback + 1274 
20 CoreFoundation 0x01d5d195 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53 
21 CoreFoundation 0x01cc1ff2 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146 
22 CoreFoundation 0x01cc08da __CFRunLoopRun + 2218 
23 CoreFoundation 0x01cbfd84 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212 
24 CoreFoundation 0x01cbfc9b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123 
25 GraphicsServices 0x026527d8 GSEventRunModal + 190 
26 GraphicsServices 0x0265288a GSEventRun + 103 
27 UIKit 0x00817626 UIApplicationMain + 1163 
28 Arbonne 0x0000324f main + 127 
29 Arbonne 0x00002c55 start + 53
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes
2. No, but you would probably get an unrecognized selector error from *within* that method once you try to do something with it - e.g. if you are expecting an array and you pass in a string, then try to get an object from your "array", you will get an error at that point.